# how to mount a Host volume to node.js docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, volume, mount

```
sudo docker run -p 3000:3000 -d --name mca-service myteam/reponame
```

this is the command i usually using to run the container. i have a folder in /var/log/appLog. i need to mount this directory with the contaner to store my app log file to make it persistent. i tried

```
sudo docker run  -p 3000:3000 -d --name mca-service  -v  /var/log/appLog:/var/log/appLog:rw --entrypoint  myteam/reponame
```

this command. but it raise some errors. can someone please help me to do this?

Comment: what error you are getting??

Answer (score 0):

Under which user is your container (myteam/reponame) running? If it is not root, you have to change the user and group and the read/write permission of your folder on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Your `--entrypoint` is empty. Either remove it or use `--entrypoint []`